# How to set RUNPATH without setting RPATH

Tags: linux, gcc

I built a binary using premake (gmake) that links dynamically to another. When I then tried to run the binary, it complained that it can't find the dynamic library.

`ldd` on the binary and of course the dynamic library is `=> Not Found!`

Of course I can `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path of the dynamic library`> but I don't want that.

I would like that the binary to work out of the box, on different machines (assuming the dynamic library location doesn't change of course)

1- How do people do this? Do they set `RPATH` all the time through come linker flags?

From what I gathered, `RUNPATH` can be over-ridden by `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but that's not the case for `RPATH`.

There's the `-rpath` and `--enable-new-dtags` options that will instruct `gcc` (or the linker to be more precise) to set both `RUNPATH` and `RPATH` to the same value, but that's not what I want really, and I can't even see the point of that.

2- What is the point of that?

3- Am I missing something? how can I set `RUN_PATH` only, so that in general the dependencies are found automatically (in `RUN_PATH`) unless instructed to search a specific path using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` first.

Answer (score 0):

on my laptop the paths are probably different from yours, but the "-d" option should do it.

Usage: c:/strawberry/c/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.3/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe [options] file...

Options:
  -d, -dc, -dp                Force common symbols to be defined

Answer (score 0):

> "to set both `RUNPATH` and `RPATH` to the same value"

That is only for backward compatibility purposes for old `ld.so`s which did not yet know `RUNPATH`.
New `ld.so`s according to its man page:

> Using the directories specified in the `DT_RPATH` dynamic section
> attribute of the binary if present and `DT_RUNPATH` attribute does not
> exist. Use of `DT_RPATH` is deprecated.

So using both `RUNPATH` and `RPATH` is in fact the best option of all and it behaves as if only has been set.
Moreover when I try it on Fedora 36 x86_64 it even no longer sets `RPATH`:

> `$ :|gcc -fPIC -shared -Wl,-rpath,$PWD,--enable-new-dtags -x c -;readelf`
> `-Wd a.out|grep -i path   0x000000000000001d (RUNPATH)            Library runpath: [/tmp]`

Also Fedora 36 started to even default to this behavior (`--enable-new-dtags`).